# SELECT...FOR UPDATE with multiple TRANSACTIONS

Tags: mysql, sql, transactions, scalability

I have a `mysql Innodb` table `m` with the following schema
`id, name, type , newid`
and the combination of `name, type ,newid` has to be unique. I have 2 set of `types`, and hence for both of them, the newid has to be sequential. (I cannot do anything with the first `id` field)
I have written a transaction that would go as follows

```
begin
select max(newid) where name = name and type = type  =>fetchedID
insert into m values (name, type, fetchedID+1)
commit
```

Now this runs fine for a normal entry. But for a scalable system, with multiple entries to be inserted at the same time, I was running into a problem where same `fetchedID` were fetched to 2 different entries (the `max(newid)` was fetching same values for multiple transactions viz. concurrent read).

So a little SO and googling helped me get to
`SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` solution.

But this holds the db lock for enough time so that other transactions ready for execution will fail. How do I make this system working and scalable.

Comment: Simple answer is: you cannot make this work in a concurrent environment. Forget newid being a sequential number, use uuid or timestamp (if you want to indicate order) instead.

Comment: @Shadow but that is the whole task. To get a sequential id for the mentioned set. Also, correct me if I am wront, by concurrent you mean multiple clients accessing and trying to alter the table at same time, right ?

Comment: Why do you need a seqential id?

Comment: If something has to be unique, add a unique index. Then, the 2nd insert at the same time will cause an error, and you can just repeat it (e.g. with +2, or by reselecting the max()).

Comment: You do not need to maintain your own sequential ID.  Use an ```IDENTITY``` type or ```SEQUENCE```.